# Hiding columns when running a query

Tags: calculated-columns

I am looking at a macro which would hide columns for a particular range every time I run the query.

For example: For the first time when I run the query, I would need Columns A to D to be hidden, like wise the next time I run the query, I would need columns E to H to be hidden.

Its basically a query that would generalize the column hiding pattern.

I request your expertise in this regard.

Comment: columns in _what_ system, exactly?

Comment: I am trying to Work on Microsoft Excel 2003 version

Answer (score 0):

The procedure below will hide columns A to D if you pass a RunCount value of 1, columns E to H if you pass a value of 2, columns I to L if you pass a value of 3, and so on and so forth...

```
Public Sub HideColumns(RunCount As Integer, TargetSheet As Worksheet)
  Dim rngHide As Range
  Dim ColOffset As Integer

' Initialise rngHide to columns A to D of the target worksheet.
  Set rngHide = TargetSheet.[A:D]

' Calculate the offset from column A to the first column _
  that needs to be hidden, update rngHide if required.
  ColOffset = (RunCount - 1) * 4
  If ColOffset > 0 Then
    Set rngHide = rngHide.Offset(0, ColOffset)
  End If

' Hide the columns.
  rngHide.ColumnWidth = 0
End Sub
```

If you decide you only want to hide certain columns, just change the line:

```
Set rngHide = TargetSheet.[A:D]
```

---

E.g. To hide only the first & last columns, (column A *and* D, column E *and* H, etc.):

```
Set rngHide = TargetSheet.[A:A, D:D]
```

To hide only the first two columns:

```
Set rngHide = TargetSheet.[A:B]
```